# pass cookie and reload one frame from another frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have main html page which have two frames frame1 and frame2. In frame1, a textbox & a button where the button click passes the value in textbox to a cookie. In frame2 this value passed through cookie is used. I need to refresh or reload the frame2 page as & when the cookie value is changed from the button click event on frame1. Any suggestions for achieving this???

Comment: Are the frames on the same domain, or on a different one?

Comment: I'm using the frameset element in Html.Frames are on the same domain.